# Guava Cache CacheStats all zero

Tags: java, caching, guava

I'm using Guava Cache lib ,and i wanna check the statistics of the cache here is my code :

```
refreshCache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
           .refreshAfterWrite(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
           .maximumSize(5)
           .recordStats()
           .build(
               new CacheLoader<String, Map<String,Object>>() {
                 public Map<String,Object> load(String key) throws Exception {
                     loader();
                 }
               });
        stats = refreshCache.stats();
        delta = refreshCache.stats()
                .minus(stats);

}

 logger.info("Stats:{}",stats);
 logger.info("delta:{}",delta);
```

i've called `recordeStats()` to active the Stats , but when i print the stats , it's all 0 .[image]

Comment: are you sure the cache is used? Print something in loader too se if it gets activated at all

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to JavaDoc:

Cache statistics are incremented according to the following rules:

- When a cache lookup encounters an existing cache entry hitCount is incremented.
- When a cache lookup first encounters a missing cache entry, a new entry is loaded.
- After successfully loading an entry missCount and loadSuccessCount are incremented, and the total loading time, in nanoseconds, is added to totalLoadTime.
- When an exception is thrown while loading an entry, missCount and loadExceptionCount are incremented, and the total loading time, in nanoseconds, is added to totalLoadTime.
- Cache lookups that encounter a missing cache entry that is still loading will wait for loading to complete (whether successful or not) and then increment missCount.--
- When an entry is evicted from the cache, evictionCount is incremented.
- No stats are modified when a cache entry is invalidated or manually removed.
- No stats are modified by operations invoked on the asMap view of the cache.

A lookup is specifically defined as an invocation of one of the methods LoadingCache.get(Object), LoadingCache.getUnchecked(Object), Cache.get(Object, Callable), or LoadingCache.getAll(Iterable).

Answer (score 44):

You forgot to activate the cache recording by adding `recordStats()` to `CacheBuilder.newBuilder()`.

Comment: This problem happened to be, although I was loading things before checking the cache. I forgot I had to specify this when building! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you aren't actually using the cache before getting its stats... why is it surprising that the stats are all 0?

Answer (score 2):

You can not instantiate stats(). It is a factory which copies over the cache values to a final statistic.
So please use logger.info(refreshCache.stats()) during runtime.

Comment: logger.info(refreshCache.stats().toString()) worked for me! :)